# Manipulating a Bootstrap nav with dropdowns so 1 dropdown is always exposed on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a standard Bootstrap (3.3.7) nav item with 2 dropdown menus. Upon loading the page, the first dropdown item in the nav should be exposed by default. When hovering over the second dropdown item, that item should now be the only exposed dropdown until the first is hovered over again. Clicking anywhere on the page should not close any dropdown menu, and clicking on the name of the dropdown (Dropdown #1, etc) must function as a link.

I currently have it so the nav is exposed by default and the nav switches on hover, but clicking anywhere on the page closes the dropdown and I do not know how to override this. Also, is there a better way to have the first item defaulted to open?

My code looks something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(".nav li.dropdown");
    $dropdown.first().addClass('open');
    $dropdown.hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $dropdown.removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="test-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown #1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown #2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default action of [hide.bs.dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events) while closing (removing open class) current dropdown on element click. It's enough to add:

```
$dropdown.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
$(".nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu").on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('li.dropdown').toggleClass('open forceclose');
})
```

And avoid to add open class to current dropdown if it has the class forceclose.

```js
$(".nav li.dropdown").on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(".nav li.dropdown").removeClass('open');
        if ($(this).is('.forceclose')) {
            $(this).removeClass('forceclose');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
    }
}).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).first().addClass('open');


$(".nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu").on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('li.dropdown').toggleClass('open forceclose');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="test-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="http://google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown #1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="http://google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown #2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought if I tried to prevent the hide.bs.dropdown event it would break the dropdown functionality, but I guess since I am bypassing it anyways by adding the class via other means that is the most logical way to do it.